# Dual Simplex Method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Suppose that in a Linear Programming problem in the **dual** Simplex Method
there is a first element (in the first column) negative. If there are in that pivot row some negative numbers we take $\max$ from the first row and that pivot row.
But what if all the elements in the pivot row are positive, what pivot do we use, i.e. which column?
Consider this table
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
-4& 0 & 1&5&16&0&4&0 \\ \hline
-12& 0 & 8&-1&-7&0&-3&1 \\ \hline
1& 1 & 1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$ 
We take -3 in the second row. OTHER **new initial** TABLE:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
-4& 0 & 1&5&16&0&4&0 \\ \hline
-12& 0 & 8&1&7&0&3&1 \\ \hline
-1& 1 & 1&1&1&1&1&-1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
What do we take here? Note that the first and last element in the last row have
the opposite signs in compared with the previous table.

Comment: A numerical example might be helpful to answer your question. There are multiple related questions which are linked on the right side of this page.

Comment: After $254$ ($\textbf{ !}$) questions you should be able to make a table. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/) you can find the code.

Comment: Your code has helped. Is my edited question OK now?

Comment: Great job (+1). Maybe it would be helpful if you provide the problem before you transformed  into tables. At the moment I just think:"Have she/he made all the steps right before? And what was the original problem?" But this are my thoughts.

Comment: May I suppose that I have these tables at the very beginning? I wanted to separate the first column and the first row by double line as here: = and || but I didn't succeeded.

Comment: Your tables are almost perfect. The name of the columns are missing. And as I said I would need a little more context to give a useful hint or answer.

Comment: By NEXT TABLE I do **not** mean that it is obtained by the Gaussian elimination with some pivot. Rather that they are two different initial tables. Does this help in understanding my question?

Answer (score 0):

In a problem that you use dual simplex to solve it, if you have a negative RHS and all the elements in that row are non-negative, then your original problem is infeasible and your dual problem is unbounded.