# Linear programming/seeing feasibility and unboudedness

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

Consider the dual linear programming problem and its simplex dually feasible table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
-4& 0 & 1&5&16&0&4&0 \\ \hline
-12& 0 & -8&-1&-7&0&-3&-1 \\ \hline
-1& 1 & 1&1&1&1&1&-1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
In the first row is our objective function.
Now see the second row:
can we easily determine that the **dual** problem is either infeasible or
unbounded? What is an **intuition** for this observation, how can we see the
unboudednes or infeasibillity for the dual problem, whichever is the acutal case? I.e. how can we *modify* the solution to see this?

Comment: You need to clarify better. The first row is objective, but what are each of the columns? Is it min or max?

Comment: @EhsanK It is $\max$. The left column is the RHS of the system.

Answer (score 0):

In primal simplex, if for any nonbasic column that can enter the basis (positive reduced cost), all the elements are non-positive, then the problem is unbounded. In dual simplex, if there is an entering variable (negative rhs) but all the elements in front of it in the row are non-negative, then the dual problem is unbounded. You can also refer to this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3186640/444582).